# My XAMPP asks for a nonexistent username and password when using the public IP address or my No-IP domain

Tags: xampp, noip

so i was making a server for a CPPS (club penguin private server) and it works fine when i use the private IP address. However, it is asking for a username and password when I login using the public IP address or my No-IP domain name. if I put in too many incorrect password attempts, it will send me to a 404.
I dont know what im doing wrong, so please give me some solutions
[my No-IP thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upQDZ.png)

I tried to use help from some other questions, but to no luck. it just keeps giving me a login and a 404 page

Some more info is that I'm using it in a windows 8 virtual machine, so that could be the problem, but it does send me to the right location so I dont know